# `first_published_at` not working properly in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I have below `PageDetail` model defined:

```
class PostDetail(Page):
    template = "Post_Detail.html"
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField("body"),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("body"),
    ]
```

but when I added 2 `PageDetail` pages (with 15 mins time interval), I found `first_published_at` was not working properly.
[image]
**Q1:** `first_published_at` of above 2 newly-added pages are the same Date and Time instead of 15 mins difference.

**Q2:** Even though I have `WAGTAIL_USER_TIME_ZONES = ['Asia/Singapore']` in `settings.py` of Django Project and restarted the Django server, the `first_published_at` is still not in correct timezone.

**Problem Solved**
It turned out to be my silly mistake.  In the template file (see below) of Post Index page, problem was fixed after I changed `page.first_published_at` to `post.first_published_at`.

```
{% for post in page.get_children %}
        <h2><a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p>{{ post.first_published_at }}</p>
        <!-- {{ post.specific.body|richtext }} -->
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are your Django settings for timezones? Do you have:

```
TIME_ZONE = ['Asia/Singapore']
USE_TZ = True
```

From the docs it looks to me like WAGTAIL_USER_TIME_ZONES is about the admin display parameter rather than what timezone the server is using.

> Logged-in users can choose their current time zone for the admin interface in the account settings.

Comment: thanks for reply. I did have `TIME_ZONE= 'Asia/Singapore'` and `USE_TZ=True` in place, but problem still persisted.